# Tensorboard not working with after upgrading tensorflow from 2.1.2 to 2.3.0

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorboard

I was using TensorFlow 2.1.2 and TensorBoard 2.4.1,

```
import os, shutil
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)

SUMMARY_DIR = 'summary/testing_this'
if 1:
    # SUMMARY_DIR is the path of the directory where the tensorboard SummaryWriter files are written
    # the directory is removed, if it already exists
    if os.path.exists(SUMMARY_DIR):
        shutil.rmtree(SUMMARY_DIR)

    train_summary_writer = tf.summary.create_file_writer(os.path.join(SUMMARY_DIR, 'train'))
    test_summary_writer  = tf.summary.create_file_writer(os.path.join(SUMMARY_DIR, 'test'))
    train_summary_counter = 0

for i in range(100):
    with train_summary_writer.as_default():
        tf.summary.scalar('train/sampled-softmax loss', i+5, step=train_summary_counter)                
        train_summary_counter += 1
```

The code written above worked perfectly fine. But as I upgraded to TensorFlow 2.3.0, the following error was thrown-

```
Serving TensorBoard on localhost; to expose to the network, use a proxy or pass --bind_all
TensorBoard 2.4.1 at http://localhost:6006/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
E0216 07:39:53.581997 140588167055104 _internal.py:113] Error on request:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 124, in read_chunk_len
    _len = int(line.strip(), 16)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16: '------WebKitFormBoundary20rNOiiimzABSId3'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/formparser.py", line 131, in wrapper
    return f(self, stream, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/formparser.py", line 253, in _parse_multipart
    form, files = parser.parse(stream, boundary, content_length)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/formparser.py", line 584, in parse
    return self.cls(form), self.cls(files)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/datastructures.py", line 419, in __init__
    for key, value in mapping or ():
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/formparser.py", line 582, in <genexpr>
    form = (p[1] for p in formstream if p[0] == "form")
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/formparser.py", line 537, in parse_parts
    for ellt, ell in self.parse_lines(file, boundary, content_length):
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/formparser.py", line 451, in parse_lines
    terminator = self._find_terminator(iterator)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/formparser.py", line 368, in _find_terminator
    for line in iterator:
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 721, in make_line_iter
    first_item = next(_iter, "")
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 681, in _make_chunk_iter
    item = _read(buffer_size)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 137, in readinto
    self._len = self.read_chunk_len()
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 126, in read_chunk_len
    raise IOError("Invalid chunk header")
OSError: Invalid chunk header

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 124, in read_chunk_len
    _len = int(line.strip(), 16)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16: 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="tag"'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 323, in run_wsgi
    execute(self.server.app)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 312, in execute
    application_iter = app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboard/backend/application.py", line 526, in __call__
    return self._app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboard/backend/application.py", line 567, in wrapper
    return wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboard/backend/security_validator.py", line 80, in __call__
    return self._application(environ, start_response_proxy)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboard/backend/path_prefix.py", line 71, in __call__
    return self._application(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboard/backend/experiment_id.py", line 76, in __call__
    return self._application(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboard/backend/empty_path_redirect.py", line 47, in __call__
    return self._application(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboard/backend/application.py", line 590, in wrapper
    return wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboard/backend/application.py", line 549, in _route_request
    return self.exact_routes[clean_path](environ, start_response)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/wrappers/base_request.py", line 238, in application
    resp = f(*args[:-2] + (request,))
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboard/plugins/scalar/scalars_plugin.py", line 166, in scalars_multirun_route
    tags = request.form.getlist("tag")
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/utils.py", line 90, in __get__
    value = self.func(obj)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/wrappers/base_request.py", line 480, in form
    self._load_form_data()
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/wrappers/base_request.py", line 319, in _load_form_data
    self._get_stream_for_parsing(), mimetype, content_length, options
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/formparser.py", line 232, in parse
    return parse_func(self, stream, mimetype, content_length, options)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/formparser.py", line 138, in wrapper
    chunk = stream.read(1024 * 64)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 137, in readinto
    self._len = self.read_chunk_len()
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 126, in read_chunk_len
    raise IOError("Invalid chunk header")
OSError: Invalid chunk header
E0216 07:39:53.585781 140588158662400 _internal.py:113] Error on request:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 124, in read_chunk_len
    _len = int(line.strip(), 16)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16: '------WebKitFormBoundary4NW6Hm666U0prn4r'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/formparser.py", line 131, in wrapper
    return f(self, stream, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/formparser.py", line 253, in _parse_multipart
    form, files = parser.parse(stream, boundary, content_length)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/formparser.py", line 584, in parse
    return self.cls(form), self.cls(files)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/datastructures.py", line 419, in __init__
    for key, value in mapping or ():
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/formparser.py", line 582, in <genexpr>
    form = (p[1] for p in formstream if p[0] == "form")
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/formparser.py", line 537, in parse_parts
    for ellt, ell in self.parse_lines(file, boundary, content_length):
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/formparser.py", line 451, in parse_lines
    terminator = self._find_terminator(iterator)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/formparser.py", line 368, in _find_terminator
    for line in iterator:
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 721, in make_line_iter
    first_item = next(_iter, "")
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 681, in _make_chunk_iter
    item = _read(buffer_size)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 137, in readinto
    self._len = self.read_chunk_len()
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 126, in read_chunk_len
    raise IOError("Invalid chunk header")
OSError: Invalid chunk header

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 124, in read_chunk_len
    _len = int(line.strip(), 16)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16: 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="tag"'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 323, in run_wsgi
    execute(self.server.app)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 312, in execute
    application_iter = app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboard/backend/application.py", line 526, in __call__
    return self._app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboard/backend/application.py", line 567, in wrapper
    return wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboard/backend/security_validator.py", line 80, in __call__
    return self._application(environ, start_response_proxy)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboard/backend/path_prefix.py", line 71, in __call__
    return self._application(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboard/backend/experiment_id.py", line 76, in __call__
    return self._application(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboard/backend/empty_path_redirect.py", line 47, in __call__
    return self._application(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboard/backend/application.py", line 590, in wrapper
    return wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboard/backend/application.py", line 549, in _route_request
    return self.exact_routes[clean_path](environ, start_response)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/wrappers/base_request.py", line 238, in application
    resp = f(*args[:-2] + (request,))
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboard/plugins/scalar/scalars_plugin.py", line 166, in scalars_multirun_route
    tags = request.form.getlist("tag")
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/utils.py", line 90, in __get__
    value = self.func(obj)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/wrappers/base_request.py", line 480, in form
    self._load_form_data()
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/wrappers/base_request.py", line 319, in _load_form_data
    self._get_stream_for_parsing(), mimetype, content_length, options
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/formparser.py", line 232, in parse
    return parse_func(self, stream, mimetype, content_length, options)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/formparser.py", line 138, in wrapper
    chunk = stream.read(1024 * 64)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 137, in readinto
    self._len = self.read_chunk_len()
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 126, in read_chunk_len
    raise IOError("Invalid chunk header")
OSError: Invalid chunk header
E0216 07:39:53.721650 140588158662400 _internal.py:113] Error on request:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 124, in read_chunk_len
    _len = int(line.strip(), 16)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16: '------WebKitFormBoundaryQo6LrfWENvCGlGD7'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/formparser.py", line 131, in wrapper
    return f(self, stream, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/formparser.py", line 253, in _parse_multipart
    form, files = parser.parse(stream, boundary, content_length)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/formparser.py", line 584, in parse
    return self.cls(form), self.cls(files)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/datastructures.py", line 419, in __init__
    for key, value in mapping or ():
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/formparser.py", line 582, in <genexpr>
    form = (p[1] for p in formstream if p[0] == "form")
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/formparser.py", line 537, in parse_parts
    for ellt, ell in self.parse_lines(file, boundary, content_length):
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/formparser.py", line 451, in parse_lines
    terminator = self._find_terminator(iterator)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/formparser.py", line 368, in _find_terminator
    for line in iterator:
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 721, in make_line_iter
    first_item = next(_iter, "")
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 681, in _make_chunk_iter
    item = _read(buffer_size)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 137, in readinto
    self._len = self.read_chunk_len()
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 126, in read_chunk_len
    raise IOError("Invalid chunk header")
OSError: Invalid chunk header

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 124, in read_chunk_len
    _len = int(line.strip(), 16)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16: 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="tag"'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 323, in run_wsgi
    execute(self.server.app)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 312, in execute
    application_iter = app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboard/backend/application.py", line 526, in __call__
    return self._app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboard/backend/application.py", line 567, in wrapper
    return wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboard/backend/security_validator.py", line 80, in __call__
    return self._application(environ, start_response_proxy)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboard/backend/path_prefix.py", line 71, in __call__
    return self._application(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboard/backend/experiment_id.py", line 76, in __call__
    return self._application(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboard/backend/empty_path_redirect.py", line 47, in __call__
    return self._application(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboard/backend/application.py", line 590, in wrapper
    return wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboard/backend/application.py", line 549, in _route_request
    return self.exact_routes[clean_path](environ, start_response)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/wrappers/base_request.py", line 238, in application
    resp = f(*args[:-2] + (request,))
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboard/plugins/scalar/scalars_plugin.py", line 166, in scalars_multirun_route
    tags = request.form.getlist("tag")
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/utils.py", line 90, in __get__
    value = self.func(obj)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/wrappers/base_request.py", line 480, in form
    self._load_form_data()
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/wrappers/base_request.py", line 319, in _load_form_data
    self._get_stream_for_parsing(), mimetype, content_length, options
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/formparser.py", line 232, in parse
    return parse_func(self, stream, mimetype, content_length, options)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/formparser.py", line 138, in wrapper
    chunk = stream.read(1024 * 64)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 137, in readinto
    self._len = self.read_chunk_len()
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 126, in read_chunk_len
    raise IOError("Invalid chunk header")
OSError: Invalid chunk header
E0216 07:39:53.824328 140588158662400 _internal.py:113] Error on request:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 124, in read_chunk_len
    _len = int(line.strip(), 16)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16: '------WebKitFormBoundaryPDuqOCLNbMBFkkSo'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/formparser.py", line 131, in wrapper
    return f(self, stream, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/formparser.py", line 253, in _parse_multipart
    form, files = parser.parse(stream, boundary, content_length)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/formparser.py", line 584, in parse
    return self.cls(form), self.cls(files)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/datastructures.py", line 419, in __init__
    for key, value in mapping or ():
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/formparser.py", line 582, in <genexpr>
    form = (p[1] for p in formstream if p[0] == "form")
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/formparser.py", line 537, in parse_parts
    for ellt, ell in self.parse_lines(file, boundary, content_length):
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/formparser.py", line 451, in parse_lines
    terminator = self._find_terminator(iterator)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/formparser.py", line 368, in _find_terminator
    for line in iterator:
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 721, in make_line_iter
    first_item = next(_iter, "")
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 681, in _make_chunk_iter
    item = _read(buffer_size)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 137, in readinto
    self._len = self.read_chunk_len()
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 126, in read_chunk_len
    raise IOError("Invalid chunk header")
OSError: Invalid chunk header

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 124, in read_chunk_len
    _len = int(line.strip(), 16)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16: 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="tag"'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 323, in run_wsgi
    execute(self.server.app)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 312, in execute
    application_iter = app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboard/backend/application.py", line 526, in __call__
    return self._app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboard/backend/application.py", line 567, in wrapper
    return wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboard/backend/security_validator.py", line 80, in __call__
    return self._application(environ, start_response_proxy)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboard/backend/path_prefix.py", line 71, in __call__
    return self._application(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboard/backend/experiment_id.py", line 76, in __call__
    return self._application(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboard/backend/empty_path_redirect.py", line 47, in __call__
    return self._application(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboard/backend/application.py", line 590, in wrapper
    return wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboard/backend/application.py", line 549, in _route_request
    return self.exact_routes[clean_path](environ, start_response)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/wrappers/base_request.py", line 238, in application
    resp = f(*args[:-2] + (request,))
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboard/plugins/scalar/scalars_plugin.py", line 166, in scalars_multirun_route
    tags = request.form.getlist("tag")
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/utils.py", line 90, in __get__
    value = self.func(obj)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/wrappers/base_request.py", line 480, in form
    self._load_form_data()
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/wrappers/base_request.py", line 319, in _load_form_data
    self._get_stream_for_parsing(), mimetype, content_length, options
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/formparser.py", line 232, in parse
    return parse_func(self, stream, mimetype, content_length, options)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/formparser.py", line 138, in wrapper
    chunk = stream.read(1024 * 64)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 137, in readinto
    self._len = self.read_chunk_len()
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 126, in read_chunk_len
    raise IOError("Invalid chunk header")
OSError: Invalid chunk header
```

Can somebody please help me run tensorboard with tf 2.3.0?

Answer (score 7):

Downgrading with `pip install 'tensorboard<2.4'` fixed this for me.

It seems tensorboard 2.4 made some breaking change.

Comment: Possibly related to https://github.com/chaoleili/jupyterlab_tensorboard/issues/25

Comment: The issue is still there with Tensorboard 2.10.
I opened an issue on Github: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/issues/6032